# Power BI Row-level security (RLS) if PART of a field is matched (not the entire field)

Tags: powerbi, dax, reporting

I have setup my RLS quite successful. I collect the user who is logged on, have setup roles and also manage to limit rows to use in the reporting.
There is a field, that contains the row's responsible person (john@doe.com).

The DAX filter `[RowResponsible] = [UsersEmail]` works just fine.

The thing is, that the `[RowResponsible]` may contain multiple values. For example `john@doe.com;jane@doe.com`.

The DAX filter `[RowResponsible] = [UsersEmail]` will no longer work, obviously.
I'd like to be able to use some form of 'contains' in this filter, but SEARCH / CONTAINSSTRING will not do the trick (they seem to be not supported).
[image: DAX Expression]

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

This following code should work for you as I am using a same code for one of mine RLS and its working fine-

```
CONTAINSSTRING(
    [RowResponsible],
    [UserEmail]
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this, but with this being set, it simply display's all rows. Only with a literal comparison, RLS works fine.